# How to extract all table details in Oracle DB using PL/SQL

Tags: sql, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, plsqldeveloper

I using Oracle PL/SQL and i need to export all the tables in that database along with their column attributes like column name, type , nullable , default value ,storage , comments

Is there any query be used to pull up this data from database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

Using SQLDeveloper: Tools -> Database Export

[Exporting Metadata and Data for a Table](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E17781_01/server.112/e18804/impexp.htm)

[image]

Alternatively you can use metadata information and build custom query.
Some tips in links below:

- [Generate table DDL tips](http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_tips_dbms_metadata.htm)
- [`DBMS_METADATA` documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14258/d_metada.htm)

  ```
  select dbms_metadata.get_ddl('TABLE','TABLE_NAME','TABLE_OWNER') 
  from dual
  ```

Answer (score 0):

Describe some system tables for what you ask and much more:

```
desc all_tab_cols;
desc all_tab_comments;
desc all_col_comments;
```

There's also user_tab_cols, etc which are a subset of the above.